# SHS Interferometer and diffraction limit

Tags: optics, spectroscopy, interferometry

I'm currently researching Spatial Heterodyned Spectrometers (SHS) and I'm a bit at a loss understanding the influence of the diffraction limit.

I'll be measuring a diffuse visible light source with entrance/exit optics, which will would limit the images resolution on the sensor. Can I see fringe patterns smaller than this limit or are they blurred out?

Any sources would be helpful, as I could not find anything on this problem (neither pro nor con).